# How to covert the python file to dmg on MAC

Tags: python, tkinter, converters

I try to convert my python code to dmg file and I used py2app method. My code can run well via visual studio code, but after I used py2app method, I cannot open the Application file. It shows The application “molarity_calculators” can’t be opened

```
from tkinter import* 

import pyperclip 
import math

win = Tk() 
win.title("Concentration Calculators") 
win.geometry("400x450+200+200")
win.config(bg="#323232")

title_text = Label(text="Concentration Calculators", fg="skyblue",bg="#323232") 
title_text.config(font="微軟正黑體 20")
title_text.pack()

mw = Label(text="Molecular Weight: ", fg="white",bg="#323232")
mw.pack()
mw_entry = Entry(justify='center') 
mw_entry.pack()

weight = Label(text="Mass of Solute(mg): ", fg="white",bg="#323232")
weight.pack()
weight_entry= Entry(justify='center')
weight_entry.pack()

volumn= Label(text="Total Solution Volumn(ml): ", fg="white",bg="#323232")
volumn.pack()
volumn_entry= Entry(justify='center')
volumn_entry.pack()

conc= Label(text="Concentration(mM): ", fg="white",bg="#323232")
conc.pack()
conc_entry= Entry(justify='center')
conc_entry.pack()

molar_show = Label(text="", fg="white",bg="#323232" )
molar_show.pack()


def gen_conc ():
    ms1 = weight_entry.get()
    mw2 = mw_entry.get()
    vol = volumn_entry.get()
    conc = conc_entry.get()

    gen_conc= ((float(ms1)/float(mw2))/float(vol))*1000

    molar_show.config(text= str(gen_conc)+ " mM")

def copy():
    xy = molar_show.cget("text")
    pyperclip.copy(xy) 

generate_btn = Button(text="Concentration", command= gen_conc) 
generate_btn.pack()


copy_btn = Button(text="copy result", command = copy)
copy_btn.pack()



win.mainloop()



from setuptools import setup

APP = ['molarity_calculators.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation':True, }

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, do you intend to distribute this to others?  Because you don't need to make it a dmg file to put it in your path.  You can add a `#! /usr/bin/env python3` to the top, copy it to `/usr/local/bin` and do `chmod +x` to make it executable.

Comment: I think you need to add `pyperclip` module explicitly when using py2app.